# I need help to shorten or simplify one sed command

Tags: sed, splunk

I like to convert `(4)wdcp(9)microsoft(3)com(0)` to `wdcp.microsoft.com`  using sed (only) as part of a `rex` in Splunk

So remove first and last parentheses with number, and replace middle one with a dot.

I do manage to do it using this two long an ugly commands.

```
echo "(4)wdcp(9)microsoft(3)com(0)" | sed -r 's/(^\([0-9]+\)|\([0-9]+\)$)//g;s/\([0-9]+\)/./g'
wdcp.microsoft.com
```

Can this be simplified and hopefully shorten to one command and not two

PS, there may be more than three part url.  eks [www.microsoft.co.uk](http://www.microsoft.co.uk)

Comment: `sed` does not support conditional replacement patterns. You may do it with `perl` where you may use `e` option, not `sed`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok thanks for info.  This is in Splunk, that has SED as a built in function.

Comment: noted that this is actually about *Splunk* in the question :)

Comment: @warren Did tag the post with "Splunk" from the start, but easier to see in the post :)

Comment: @Jotne - that's why I made the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

This works: `sed 's/([0-9]*)//1 ;s//./g; s/\.$//'`

Delete the first, use `//` to repeat the match and replace the rest with `.`, then fix the trailing `.`

That is about as succinct as I can get it while maintaining your functionality. It's much more confusing than your replacements, though.

The space after the 1 seems required for some seds.